# When can we use an indefinite singular noun as a subject in the start of a sentence?

Tags: definite-articles

I was told not to use an indefinite singular noun as a subject in the start of a sentence, so I can say such to refer to a general phenomenon:

> Cats eat mouses.
>
> A cat eats mouses.
>
> The cat eats mouses.

but not

> *Cat eat mouses.

Anyway, I have seen a lot of sentences with an indefinite singular noun as a subject:

> French food is delicious.

and typically, they are often some more abstract things:

> Philosophy is interesting.

and more exceptions. I remember there must be many exceptions with non-abstract nouns in indefinite singular, but I cannot come up now.

Comment: Both food and philosophy are uncountable nouns. Your rule would apply to countable singular nouns in a standard text (with the  exception of phrases like 'boy meets girl' or contracted newspaper headings and the like).

Comment: @SConroy In the case of countable nouns, should I only use "German burgers are delicious" but not "a German burger is delicious" nor "The German burger is delicious" if I talk generally?

Comment: "German burgers are delicious." "A German burger makes a delicious lunch." (because you're eating only one burger). "The German burger was the prototype for my restaurant's burger." (because you're talking about the concept).